# Find all rows containing a key and concatenate cell values

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Here is the sheet that contains datas:

```
Team           | Hero
---------------+----------------
Avengers       | Captain America
Justice League | Superman
Avengers       | Iron Man
Avengers       | Hulk
Justice League | Green Lantern
Justice League | Batman
Avengers       | Thor
Avengers       | Wolverine
```

I want to get the names of heroes from Avengers team.

With VLOOKUP function, I got only the first hero of the team, i.e. **Captain America** :

```
=VLOOKUP("Avengers";A:B;2;FALSE)
```

I want to get a comma separated list like **Captain America, Iron Man, Hulk, Thor, Wolverine**.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using FILTER and JOIN formulas :

*Heroes sheet*

```
Team           | Hero
---------------+----------------
Avengers       | Captain America
Justice League | Superman
Avengers       | Iron Man
Avengers       | Hulk
Justice League | Green Lantern
Justice League | Batman
Avengers       | Thor
Avengers       | Wolverine
```

*Teams sheet*

```
Team           | Heroes                                           | Formula
---------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
Avengers       | Captain America, Iron Man, Hulk, Thor, Wolverine | =JOIN(", "; FILTER(Heroes!B:B; Heroes!A:A=A2))
Justice League | Superman, Green Lantern, Batman                  | =JOIN(", "; FILTER(Heroes!B:B; Heroes!A:A=A3))
```